# Chaining .emit( ) with EventListener in Node.js

Tags: node.js

When using the EventEmitter class in Node.js what is the best practice way to chain together different events?

Let's say I have multiple events, and I want to emit/trigger event 'B' but only inside the listener of some other initial event, 'A'. I was able to do something like that below, I'm just wondering if it is correct / memory-efficient to reference the eventEmitter instance in its own event listeners?

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';

const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
const eventTypes = ['txRequestReceived', 'txRequestComplete'];

eventEmitter.on('txRequestReceived', (params)=>{
    let {chainID, address} = params;

    console.log(`txRequestReceived event: ${chainID} -- ${address}`);
    eventEmitter.emit('txRequestComplete', {"chainID": chainID, "address": address});
});

eventEmitter.on('txRequestComplete', (params)=>{
    let {chainID, address} = params;

    console.log(`txRequestComplete event: ${chainID} -- ${address}`);
});
```

This does work, and I'm able to pass around an event payload with the listener parameters. I'm wondering if there are memory / scope issues with it? If I were to write a class and extend the EventEmitter class, would I just use the 'this' keyword to access .emit() and .on() behaviour?

Comment: For more complex event handling techniques it's mostly recommended to go the reactive way. Maybe have a look into RX.js that supports tons of event chaining techniques and highly efficient at it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find this "answer" (which I will accept). The pattern I used works, but there are caveats surrounding the fact that EventEmitter is synchronous and how closures with the handlers may handle memory.

https://www.codementor.io/@simenli/demystifying-asynchronous-programming-part-2-node-js-eventemitter-7r51ivby4